# Re: How can Django/WSGI and PHP share / on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, django, wsgi, mod-php

in response to: [How can Django/WSGI and PHP share / on Apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/226449/how-can-django-wsgi-and-php-share-on-apache/226467#226467)

Hello,

could you please post the complete config file from /sites-available

I am having a problem seems like rewrite engine redirects all requests to django, so static and php files are not served and instead i see the django 404 page. If I get rid of rewrite rule then static files and php works.

here is my apache config file from /sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/www/django
    <Directory />
            Options +FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Indexes
            AllowOverride None
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi


    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite.wsgi/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

~

and my .wsgi file:

> import site
>
> site.addsitedir('/home/user/.virtualenvs/url.com/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
>
> import os, sys
>
> path = '/home/www/django' if path not
>   in sys.path:
>       sys.path.append(path)
>
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] =
>   'mysite.settings'
>
> sys.path.append(path + '/mysite')
>   import django.core.handlers.wsgi
>
> _application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
>
> import posixpath
>   def application(environ, start_response):

```
# Wrapper to set SCRIPT_NAME to actual mount point.
environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = posixpath.dirname(environ['SCRIPT_NAME'])
if environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/':
    environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''
return _application(environ, start_response)
```

the document root directory on disk (/home/www/django) contains php files, images, and the mysite.wsgi file..
thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

figured it out

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/webdev/domains/handtrackers.com/django

    <Directory /home/www/django>

            #Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI Indexes
            AllowOverride None
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
            AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
            AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite.wsgi/$1 [QSA,PT,L]

    </Directory>
```

but specifying any Option, like the commented out one... will result in:

"Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is 
off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden:"